Mysql Create a query with variables and functions
Hello everyone I have 3 requests each of which depends on each other, in the end there should be an automatic download of the archive from the table, and so we have:
We take the wims_detections table, it has a column "id" (let's assume I have it), we access the column "detection_id" we take and remember this identifier "TY-LU-W1_20231221T155059823+0300", then we go to the table sensors_detections_data we find the value from the column data_id by this detection_id and go to the third table sensors_data there by data_id we find the file in the column "data" and download it.
If you distribute it manually, it will look like this, but you need to do it automatically, specify the id and get a file from data at the output
SELECT detection_id FROM wims_detections WHERE id = '715696';

SELECT data_id FROM sensors_detections_data WHERE detection_id = 'TY-LU-W1_20231221T155059823+0300';

SELECT * FROM sensors_data WHERE data_id = 'TY-TY-SL1_20231221T155059878+0300';



Go read up on JOINs, if you want to do all of this in one statement.

You can assign session variables in the queries:
SELECT @det_id := detection_id FROM wims_detections WHERE id = '715696';

SELECT @data_id := data_id FROM sensors_detections_data WHERE detection_id = @det_id;

SELECT * FROM sensors_data WHERE data_id = @data_id;

But the normal way to do this is with a join:
SELECT sd.*
FROM sensors_data AS sd
JOIN sensors_detection_data AS sdd ON sd.data_id = sdd.data_id
JOIN wims_detection AS wd ON sdd.detection_id = wd.detection_id
WHERE wd.id = '715696';


Good day
I also thought about substituting variables into functions, tell me now that everything works, is it possible to download this file using a request and assign it a name from the data column, attached a picture.

Yes, you could write a stored procedure where the ID you compare with wd.id is a procedure parameter.
